# Partial fraction development of $\cot \pi z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

"Compute the values $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^4}$ by comparison to the partial fraction development of $\cot \pi z$."

I'm not sure what "the partial fraction development of $\cot \pi z$" means, and how it would help to compute those sums that seem unrelated to trigonometric functions.

Comment: The partial fraction development of $\cot \pi z$ is $$\pi \cot \pi z = \frac1z + \sum_{\nu\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} \left(\frac{1}{z-\nu}-\frac{1}{\nu}\right) = \frac1z + 2\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty \frac{z}{z^2-\nu^2}.$$ If you play a bit with that, you could see how the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k}}$ arise as coefficients in the Laurent expansion. If you get the first terms of the Laurent expansion by dividing the Taylor series of $\pi \cos \pi z$ and $\sin \pi z$, you get another expression for the coefficients.